# When I do Vi I see empty lines but more doesnt show

Tags: shell, unix, vi

When I do vi on a output file I see lot of empty lines appearing .Something like

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1000000;
@
@
@
```

But when I do more on same file I dont see it. And the file appears correct.

```
 DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1000000; 
 permissibleCars =
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong as I am facing this for 1st time.

Regards/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the next line is too long to be displayed on the screen. In vim you can change this behavior by setting `'display'`:

```
set display=lastline
```